# Wordpress Theme Development

Tags: php, wordpress

what i'm currently trying to achieve is some simple theme options. What i want to b able todo is;

Under the Wordpress GUI, Theme options section which i've currently got a few setup (with no actions behind them), is to simply "Click a check box which will disable front page widgets, if it's on then show them if it's off disable them"

I understand the logic behind, but i have no idea on how to create something will will return a simple true of false, from the theme-options.php, link it into the front-page.php and use the result from theme-options to be the condition to show said area.

Any help with this would be amazing.

```
<?php $options = get_option( 'SV_theme_options' ); ?>

<input id="SV_theme_options[option1]" name="SV_theme_options[option1]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', $options['option1'] ); ?> />


/**
 * Sanitize and validate input. Accepts an array, return a sanitized array.
 */
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    // Our checkbox value is either 0 or 1
    if ( ! isset( $input['option1'] ) )
        $input['option1'] = null;
    $input['option1'] = ( $input['option1'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );

    // Say our text option must be safe text with no HTML tags
    $input['sometext'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['sometext'] );

    // Our select option must actually be in our array of select options
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $input['selectinput'], $select_options ) )
        $input['selectinput'] = null;

    // Our radio option must actually be in our array of radio options
    if ( ! isset( $input['radioinput'] ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $input['radioinput'], $radio_options ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;

    // Say our textarea option must be safe text with the allowed tags for posts
    $input['sometextarea'] = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['sometextarea'] );

    return $input;
}
```

Also in the front-page.php I've required_once for this file, tried calling by doing:

`echo theme_options_validate( $input['option1' );`

however all i get is the word Array returned.

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you made a typo.

You didn't close the bracket

```
echo theme_options_validate( $input['option1' );
```

Should be:

```
echo theme_options_validate( $input['option1'] );
```

Comment: ah sorry that was just my typo, i have included the whole thing. All i want is the result to either a 1 or a 0 so that i can then use that condition to show the widgets etc...